# Is it grammatical to use "same" or "the same" in substitution for an objective pronoun?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, pronouns

I've seen and heard this usage of the pronoun "same" more than once, and it sounded strange to my ears:

> - "Thank you for the book; I will return same shortly."
> - "Wine production has increased, but is there great demand for the same?"

Is it acceptable ?  Where?

Comment: Just a note, unworthy of a full answer response: "Same," used this way, is common in India.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don’t worry, Luis. It’s not just you. This sounds strange to **everbody’s** ears. :)

It is **possible** to use *the same* as a substantive instead of as an adjective.  However, it is in my opinion not necesssarily advisable outside of specialized fields like law and linguistics.

Here are the two main substantive possibilities:

1. Used absolutely (that is, without a noun following it, so a nominalized adjective) as in *the same*, it acts like a noun. It takes a definite determiner, but does not normally admit a plural inflection. (But see sense 5b below.)
2. Used as a pronoun, it means *it*, and so being a pronoun takes no determiner there.

It’s a very old way of speaking that today is found almost only in legalese, but from which it seems to have been snatched up by the captains of commerce to make them sound fancier.  This is usually gratuitous; for example, in your second sentence, I would advise using *this* there instead of *the same*.

This all is covered by the OED entry for *same* in sense 4a under section B:

> **B.** *absol.* and as *pron.* (Constructions as in **A.**)
>
> **4a.** ***the same***,  † ***that*** (or ***this***) ***same***: the aforesaid person or thing. Often merely the equivalent of a personal pronoun; he, she, it, they. Now *rare* in literary use; still common in legal documents; also (with reference to things) in commercial language (where *the* is sometimes omitted).

And here are some of its citations showing this sort of thing:

> - 1819 Keats *Isabella* ii, ― Her lute-string gave an echo of his name, She spoiled her half-done broidery with the same.
> - 1901 M. Franklin *My Brilliant Career* viii. 56 ― A big red-bearded man··had received a letter from Mrs. Bossier instructing him to take care of me. He informed me also that he was glad to do what he termed ‘that same’.
> - 1926 in H. W. Fowler *Mod. Eng. Usage* 512/1 ― Sir,-Having in mind the approaching General Election, it appears to me that the result of same is likely to be as much a farce as the last.
> - 1966 G. W. Turner *Eng. Lang. in Austral. & N.Z.* vi. 135 ― A different influence of written language is seen in the use of *same* as a pronoun equivalent to *it*, as in ‘put the tailboard up and secure same with a length of wire’ from New Zealand (Wally Crump, 1964), a facetious borrowing of lawyer’s English which is quite common.
> - 1973 *N.Y. Law Jrnl.* 24 July 4/4 ― The following sentence in a brief is typical of its misuse as a noun: ‘Waldbaum purchased the soda··then stacked it on the shelves in order to sell the same.’

As you see, it is not especially well looked upon in some of those citations.

However, using *same* that way is quite different from the specialized linguistic use of *sames*, which per the OED means, with two recent citations included:

> **5b.** *pl. Linguistics.* Features or utterances that are identical.
>
> - 1964 Crystal & Quirk *Syst. Prosodic & Paralinguistic Features in Eng.* iv. 49 ― We should··only subsequently look for the correlations between postulated ‘sames’ of tension and formal items in the linguistic and situational context which will enable us to make statements of meaning.
> - 1977 *Trans. Philol. Soc.* 1975 9 ― Certain configurations in languages typically result from the principled (‘lawful’) divergence over time of original sames.

It sounds more than a little bit stodgy and snooty, like someone is putting on airs.  I would be chary of using it in any situation in which that were not the intended effect.

Comment: "Stodgy and snooty"...I had to look that up.  Will I sound "stodgy and snooty" if I incorporate it (stodgy and snooty) into my vocabulary ?

Comment: @Luis No, the stodgy and snooty are not prone to using those terms; that would be talking about themselves. :)  I imagine you also had to look up *chary*. I did all those because I know you enjoy learning such words, but they are rather more literary than conversational — well, for most people’s conversations.  *Snooty* is a bit lower in register, perhaps, than is *stodgy*.

Comment: Have you by any chance observed this usage on SO? I know I have... and I can't help but notice that the only people who use it in this manner all seem to hail from the same (ha) region. Could it be a dialectal quirk?

Comment: @BoltClock Possibly. If it’s the region I’m thinking of, then they might have some leftover Victorian notions that haven’t died out, perhaps associating such high-falutin’ lingo with the upper class, and are therefore themselves now putting on the same lofty airs.

Comment: _Does_ it actually come out of legalese? The OED only says that is where it _now_ chiefly survives, but the quotations pre-1900 are as much or more from literary sources as from legal ones.

Comment: @Wlerin You’re right. I’ve modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Am I the only one who tends to find _the same_ in this use somewhat awkward but generally acceptable, but _same_ (with no article) nearly always completely and utterly bizarre and ungrammatical? Doesn't seem to matter how many times I see it, it just remains **wrong** in my head.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Not, not just you. My original draft answer said that the first version was a bit odd, but the second one was actually wrong — which is what my ear told me without research. Honest Injun! Then I looked it up and presented the new findings you see above.

Comment: Ah, good. Not just me, then.

Comment: I also came across another example of this in the _Proclamation of Rebellion_ (http://www.britannia.com/history/docs/procreb.html) which was issued by King George III in response to the American Revolutionary War and ultimately lead to the American Declaration of Independence. 

_to the obstruction of lawful commerce, and to the oppression of our loyal subjects carrying on **the same**_;

Comment: "This sounds strange to everbody’s ears." This statement is a bit condescending. There is a comment on the question saying that this use of "same" is common in India.